# Json File Opening in New Tab instead of Downloading

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular and TypeScript to send some files to the user using googleapis storage service. Whenever I send a geojson file to download, instead of downloading it to the computer, it just opens the file in a new tab without downloading it. I'm creating the file in the backend server, saving it to the google service, and then sending the download url to the user. When I use this function to download KML files, it downloads just fine, but when I try to download geojson it just opens it as plain text in a new tab. How can I make it download as a normal file?

```
const download_url = res.download_url;
saveAs(download_url, 'sample2.kml');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
downloadFile(data: Response) {
  const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(url);
}
```

Comment: This won't work, the only thing that I'm getting back from the server is the URL to download the file, I'm not getting back the entire JSON object, so this just downloads a file with the URL as the contents.